# What are the upsides of switching from ArangoDB to Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've used ArangoDB for a long time. I thinking about switching to Memgraph. What are the upsides of Memgraph? Is there a C++ driver that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding features, Memgraph is primarily a graph database, not a multi-modal database. This means that it has been optimized for different features,

If your use case is optimal for a graph database, then we will perform better, and you will have great built-in algorithms, triggers, tooling, and so on. All cool stuff related to the graphs. You can see all of the features in the [reference guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide)

One of Memgraph's distinctive features is that it is in-memory graph database.

This means that it is very fast.
Memgraph has a C/C++ `mgclient` driver for the database. More info regarding drivers and API is available in the [official documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers).